# Некорректно работает SOAP в Yii2

Tags: yii2, soap

Есть некий код

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$client = new SoapClient("http://ip/ws/ws2.1cws?wsdl",
    array(
        "login"      => "login",
        "password"      => "pass",
        "cache_wsdl"      => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        "trace"      => 1,
        "exceptions"      => 0,
    ));
$json = $client->﻿TovarToSite();
var_dump($json);
?>
```

Если я возьму просто на сервере создам файл, вставлю этот код и открою через браузер - все работает. Если я этот же код пишу в контроллере - он выдает ошибку, что нету такой функции. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Нету какой функции?

Comment: функция есть, я же написал, что если вызвать без Yii2 - все ок, если в Yii2 - говорит что нету

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю, говорит, что нету чего? Какой функции? Для полного понимая нужен код контроллера и ошибка.

Comment: говорит, что нет функции, которую я хочу вызвать через SOAP

Comment: Какую же функцию ты хочешь вызвать? Если про TovarToSite(), то это метод. Какая ошибка возникает? Создается ли объект $client?